# Sprite isn't moving

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm new to programming and, since I find it easier to learn doing, I was playing around with C++ and SFML. I was trying to get a sprite to move, but for some reason, I can't do it. I've tried everything I found, but no luck. Anyone know why this isn't working? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express and SFML 2.1, by the way.

```
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 800), "Project");
    window.setFramerateLimit(30);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    window.clear(sf::Color::White);
    window.display();
    sf::Texture charMain;
    if (!charMain.loadFromFile("Images/playerFrontSprite.png"))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    sf::Sprite charaMain;
    charaMain.setPosition(500.f , 500.f);
    charaMain.setTexture(charMain);
    window.draw(charaMain);
    window.display();
    sf::Font cavefont;
    sf::Font::Font(cavefont);
    if (!cavefont.loadFromFile("Cave-Story.ttf"))
        return 1;
        while (window.isOpen())
        {
            sf::Event playerAction;
            while (window.pollEvent(playerAction))
            {
                switch(playerAction.type)
                {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
                case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                    std::cout << "sf::Event::KeyPressed" << std::endl;
                    switch(playerAction.key.code)
                    {
                    case sf::Keyboard::W:
                        charaMain.move(0 , 1);
                        break;
                    case sf::Keyboard::A:
                        charaMain.move(-1 , 0);
                        break;
                    case sf::Keyboard::S:
                        charaMain.move(0 , -1);
                        break;
                    case sf::Keyboard::D:
                        charaMain.move(1 , 0);
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're moving the object, but you're not drawing it on the screen at its new position. Your drawing code is outside the main loop, so it never gets called after you move the sprite, so you never see the effects.

You basically need to pull the rendering code (ie. `window.draw(charaMain)` and `window.display()`) inside the `while (window.isOpen())` loop, outside the event handling loop.

Comment: @Aerdenhein: no problem! You might want to click the tick under the vote box to mark this as your accepted answer - this lets other people know your problem is solved.